# My webcam stops working when i use things related to pytorch

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, yolov5

I am trying to make a yolov5 custom detection tool. When i try to run it i get this error:-
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4062: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

I also get these two errors in the terminal before this error :-

C:\Users\Kilometre Morales/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\export.py` is shadowing the library module 'export'. Consider renaming or moving it!

global cap_msmf.cpp:1759 CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638

My webcam turns on fine if i remove everything related to pytorch.

Here is my code :-

```
import cv2
import torch
path='C:/Users/Kilometre Morales/Documents/Science Exhibition code/yolov5/yolov5win11customobj-                                  main/best.pt'
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5','custom', path, force_reload=True)
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.resize(frame,(1020,500))
    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF==27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried to make a yolov5 custom object detector. I was expecting it to run my webcam with no issues and then i could proceed with further coding. But i got this error when i runned the code.

Comment: *"if i remove everything related to pytorch."* details please. does `import torch` (and no torch.hub.load?) suffice to break the camera access?

Comment: if i remove the import, path and model the webcam starts working

Comment: yes you said that already. I understood that. I was asking what happens when you have the torch import but not the torch.hub.load. this process of elimination is explained in [mre]